# linkedin login returning 404 when trying to retrieve profile information

Tags: go, authentication, linkedin-api

I have an app on linkedin that uses the login api. It is a web app that makes use of go and the goth authentication library. Up until a few days ago my app was authenticating users fine. Now it returns this error message:

linkedin responded with a 404 trying to fetch user information

The app has been running continuously without updates for weeks. So there hasn't been any code changes.

I should mention that it does bring me to the login page but after entering my username and password it redirects and outputs the aforementioned error

The goth oauth api code is located here: https://github.com/markbates/goth/blob/master/providers/linkedin/linkedin.go

It essentially calls this url with the access token
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location:(name),picture-url,email-address)

Does anyone know if the api endpoints have changed or any other reason authentication would just stop working?

I've been checking the blog but I see no updates in regards to the api and there doesn't seem to be a way to reach linkedin developer support as it just points to stackoverflow.

Comment: Same issue seen recently - was sporadic and now failing on all server instances. However, still working on local machine so indicates they are rolling out some change via Load Balancer / DNS as not affecting everyone yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging deeper into this issue. It seems that linkedin is now returning http 2.0 responses from their api.

I discovered this by writing a small go program which I ran on my local machine and on the aws instance where the server code is located.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

const (
    bearerToken string = "AQVJampuUSuvWs5beuCvHiJYC--"
)

func main() {

    userEndpoint := "//api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-  name,last-name,headline,location:(name),picture-url,email-address)?format=json"

client := &http.Client{}

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "", nil)

req.URL = &url.URL{
    Scheme: "https",
    Host:   "api.linkedin.com",
    Opaque: userEndpoint,
}

req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+bearerToken)
resp, err := client.Do(req)

request, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(req, true)

fmt.Println("request:", string(request))

data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

response, _ := httputil.DumpResponse(resp, false)

resp.Body.Close()

fmt.Println("response:", string(response))

fmt.Println(err, req.URL.String(), string(data))
}
```

When running this on my local machine the api returned a response with the profile data. When I ran it on the aws instance it returned a 404 with an http 2.0 header

Here is an excerpt of the output of running this program on aws

request: GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.linkedin.com
Authorization: Bearer AQVJampuUSuvWs5beu--

response: HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 5530
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 18 Feb 2017 03:45:21 GMT
X-Li-Pop: prod-lva1-h2

```
<!-- EF of static content included-->
<html>
  <head>
  <title>404: Not Found</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
 /* GLOBAL */
```

Now I don't know if this a bug or expected behaviour but it appears that linkedin is returning http 2.0 responses when go is picking up causing the 404.

They way I was able to fix it was to turn off http 2.0 client support in go itself. By setting the following environment variable

GODEBUG=http2client=0

At which point the linkedin api returns the profile information.

I'm curious to know if this is a bug with linkedin or go. Hopefully someone from linkedin can chime in.

Comment: NIce piece of code. Is this javascript, by the way? It looks a little like JS, in places, but then not, in others. I would like to run it on my machine, because I am having a similar issue...

Comment: @CharlesRobertson He says "I discovered this by writing a small go program" - see https://golang.org/, Go is actually a language.

Answer (score 1):

For a few days now, we sporadically saw these errors, too.

Since today, every request seems to fail—even on my local development machine (production is AWS).

Looks like something goes wrong in the protocol negotiation process and the servers just bail out and return a standard 404 response. LinkedIn does not seem to support APLN.

My workaround right now is to create an `http.Client` that does not support HTTP/2, like so:

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSNextProto: make(map[string]func(authority string, c *tls.Conn) http.RoundTripper),
    },
}
```